Java adding hours to calendar changes the timezone
So i have a problem where i have to find the next reccuring event.
In my solution i have to add hours to a calendar, but sometimes the timezone is changing and also the date hours is changing.
Also i have to mention that i can only use classes from java.util.*; and java.text.*.
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(getDataInceput());
        while(c.getTime().before(this.dataP)) {
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, numarOre);
            System.out.println(c.getTime());
        }

In my example i have to add 24 hours to this date 2019-03-09 22:46:00.
Sun Mar 10 22:46:00 EET 2019
Mon Mar 11 22:46:00 EET 2019
Tue Mar 12 22:46:00 EET 2019
Wed Mar 13 22:46:00 EET 2019
Thu Mar 14 22:46:00 EET 2019
Fri Mar 15 22:46:00 EET 2019
Sat Mar 16 22:46:00 EET 2019
Sun Mar 17 22:46:00 EET 2019
Mon Mar 18 22:46:00 EET 2019
Tue Mar 19 22:46:00 EET 2019
Wed Mar 20 22:46:00 EET 2019
Thu Mar 21 22:46:00 EET 2019
Fri Mar 22 22:46:00 EET 2019
Sat Mar 23 22:46:00 EET 2019
Sun Mar 24 22:46:00 EET 2019
Mon Mar 25 22:46:00 EET 2019
Tue Mar 26 22:46:00 EET 2019
Wed Mar 27 22:46:00 EET 2019
Thu Mar 28 22:46:00 EET 2019
Fri Mar 29 22:46:00 EET 2019
Sat Mar 30 22:46:00 EET 2019
Sun Mar 31 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Mon Apr 01 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Tue Apr 02 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Wed Apr 03 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Thu Apr 04 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Fri Apr 05 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Sat Apr 06 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Sun Apr 07 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Mon Apr 08 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Tue Apr 09 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Wed Apr 10 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Thu Apr 11 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Fri Apr 12 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Sat Apr 13 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Sun Apr 14 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Mon Apr 15 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Tue Apr 16 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Wed Apr 17 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Thu Apr 18 23:46:00 EEST 2019
Fri Apr 19 23:46:00 EEST 2019

How can i manage this to get 2019-04-19 22:46:00.

Just in case you are not aware of this. Daylight saving time on Wikipedia

Okay, how about add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)?

Which java version do you use? Since Java 8 there is a good API for doing date/time calculations https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Do you want to "add 24 hours" or "get the next day in the same hour"?

The timezone didn't change in your case. The time switches from Eastern European Time to Eastern European Summer Time but its still the same timezone. Because the EET uses the daylight saving time the time part of your calendar changes at 31st March.
Your code could convert the date/time into UTC timezone and using to find the next event. If you need to display the date/time somewhere it could be converted back into the viewers timezone. The advantage of UTC is it doesn't use daylight saving time so you have no hour skip as in your example.
